# A triangular Hopf algebra and its unitary R-matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Why is the R-matrix of a Hopf algebra called *unitary* when it satisfies
the relation
$$R^{-1}=R_{12},$$
I would say *invertible*, why then call it unitary? Is that a nomenclature that maybe comes from physics?

Answer (score 0):

If $R^{-1}=R_{12}$, then the square of the braiding is equal to one, i.e. the category of $H$-modules is symmetric monoidal. 
I don't think "unitary" is good terminology and am not sure if it is standard, but "invertible" would not be good terminology because that simply means that $R^{-1}$ exists.